# Original image size VS displayed image size

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the size of the image displayed on my screen, not the original size of the image.

I already did some research on it and I found the same question on the unresolved [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855218/trying-to-get-the-display-size-of-an-image-in-an-imageview) two years old, so I was thinking maybe now there is a new way to do it.

I tried this 3 solutions :

```
//Get the same result for all my images (whereas images have difference sizes)
imageView.getWidth() + imageView.getHeight()

//Get the original size of the images  
imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth() + imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight()
bitMap.getWidth() + bitMap.getHeight()
```

My xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="1dip" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:contentDescription="@string/descr_image"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/loading"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:visibility="gone" />

<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update 1**

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = imageView.getViewTreeObserver();
if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
     viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
       @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
       public void onGlobalLayout() {      
           imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this)               
           System.out.println("TEST :" + imageView.getWidth() + " " + imageView.getHeight());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `ImageView` you have the width and height set to

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

The image view will fill the parent and the `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` will give you those values.

You will need to wrap your `ImageView` somehow to make it display properly but give the `ImageView` width/height values like

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

There is also an answer on [ImageView bitmap scale dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033723/imageview-bitmap-scale-dimensions) that seems to solve this problem too.

From the answer by https://stackoverflow.com/users/321697/kcoppock :

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
int scaledHeight, scaledWidth;
iv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        Rect rect = iv.getDrawable().getBounds();
        scaledHeight = rect.height();
        scaledWidth = rect.width();
        iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you it works, I am not sure why but I had to use a ViewTreeObserver otherwise the size was w:1 h:1. But with "wrap_content" my images are displayed in a "ugly way", isn't there  possibility to get the size with fill_parent parameter?

Comment: I've added some more code that might help you.  see the modified answer.