# Disable ImageView if it doesn't fit on the screen

Tags: android, imageview

I have an ImageView with a dynamic src, and I want to display it, only if there is enough place to show all of it without scaling it.
How should I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

you need to get the image size and screen size then check to see if its larger before displaying

If you want the the display dimensions in pixels you can use

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

If you don't have access to an activity to call getWindowManager on. You can use:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

For the use case you're describing however a margin/padding in the layout seems more appropriate.

then do

```
if (ImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() > height || ImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth() >width){
//dont display image
}
```

coppied and compiled from two post
[Get screen dimensions in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions)
and
[Trying to get the display size of an image in an ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855218/trying-to-get-the-display-size-of-an-image-in-an-imageview)

Comment: As I'm insdie getView, the getWidth and getHeight methods, give false values

Comment: did u try both methods? for getting the values?  can you call view.super  either way you will need to post more code then to get further help

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Comment: I don't want to scale it, but disable it if it dosen't fit

Comment: Then, owen greig answer is the best