# how to check two images on imageview are overlapping to eachother

Tags: android, image, imageview, translation, image-scaling

I am creating an application.I am overlapping two image on each other. My image is bigger than screen so imageView is adjusting it .I want to know that  images are overlapping each other  or not ...if they are not overlapping then how should i do that they overlap to each other....
this is [image: first]image now  [image: second]  image now i want to overlap this image but i want to make sure tht this image should be overlap to each other properly ........

Comment: pls elaborate your requirement , then it is easy to give proper answer for your question.

Comment: try adjusting the image size yourself so you always know how big each image is rather than relying on the system.

Comment: @Orlymee i am using n number of image and i am switching on image dynamically ......

Comment: @Ashishsingh You shall still be able to query the size of the image as it is your code that handles what goes inside that particular imageview. Once you know the the dimensions of each image you can figure out if they overlap. There are a few posts on stackoverflow which discuss that issue. Just search for android get image size

Comment: can you give a suitable link for my query.....

Comment: for image size like I said search android get image size: here are the first 2 links; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680499/android-get-height-width-of-imageview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855218/trying-to-get-the-display-size-of-an-image-in-an-imageview and here is another link to figure out if 2 rectangles overlap eachother http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306316/determine-if-two-rectangles-overlap-each-other

Comment: @Orlymee according to that i have edited my code but it is not working ........