# How to get correct ImageView width?

Tags: android, imageview, width

I would like to get a ImageView width but all my results don't get me correct values.

I tryed: `myImageView.getWidth();` but it return 0.

I also tryed: `myImageView.getMeasuredWidth();` but it return 0 too.

And I tryed: `myImageView.getLayoutParams().width;` but it return -1.

My ImageView :

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myImageViewId"
        android:src="@drawable/img"/>
```

And my activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);

    ImageView myImageView;
    myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageViewId);

    int width = myImageView.getLayoutParams().width;
    Log.d("Perso","width = "+width);
}
```

Do you know why I don't get a correct return ?
Thank's advance.

Comment: Similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463155/get-the-displayed-size-of-an-image-inside-an-imageview

Comment: Thank's, I found the solution =) I use `ImageView.getDrawable.getIntrisicWidth`. It works great =)