# Getting dimensions of bitmap inside an imageview

Tags: android, android-layout

There is a layout like on the picture. I want to know the real coordinates of the headshape image. ImageView that contains this headshape image has 40dp margin for each side and the source image is scaled proportionally.

[image]

How can I get the top and bottom coordinates of the headshape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by calculating the ratio of height-to-width of original image. And if the width is known then we can calculate the top and bottom, knowing the center.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get bounds (coordinates of corners of your image), you could go with this code:

```
Rect rectCoordinates = headShapeImageView.getDrawable().getBounds();
```

With returned `Rect` you can get all sorts of data about dimensions of your view, including coordinates of it's 4 corners. Refer to docs here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html

However, if you want to get imageView resolution instead of bounds, refer to an answer here: [Get the displayed size of an image inside an ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463155/get-the-displayed-size-of-an-image-inside-an-imageview)

Cheers!