# How to get height of Image in Imageview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

[image][image]I have set an image in imageview. It is showing in center of the screen as I have make its parent layout (Relative layout) to match parent. Imageview height and width is also set to match parent.

I want to get the height and width of Image in imageview.

I have used :

```
int imagWidth = imageView.getWidth();
int imagHeight = imageView.getHeight();
```

but by this we are getting height and width of Imageview .

Here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:src="@drawable/image2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463155/get-the-displayed-size-of-an-image-inside-an-imageview

Comment: Can you share  your xml?

Comment: @YahyaMukhtar:
I have updated my ques ..Plz check
I want to get height of my image programmatically.

Comment: @AshutoshTripathi:
I have already tried this. but It's not working.

Comment: Kindly see the answer i posted

Comment: @YahyaMukhtar: its not working

Comment: check out this link hope this will help you
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680499/how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-an-android-widget-imageview/4680660#4680660)

Comment: @Anuj: That's not working man...

Answer (score 1):

1. Using `ImageView.getDrawable().getInstrinsicWidth()` and 
   `getIntrinsicHeight()` will both return the original dimensions.
2. Getting the `Drawable` through `ImageView.getDrawable()` and casting it to a 
   `BitmapDrawable`, then using `BitmapDrawable.getBitmap().getWidth()` and 
   `getHeight()` also returns the original image and its dimensions.

try below code :

```
ImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight()//original height of underlying image
ImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth()//original width of underlying image
imageView.getMeasuredHeight();//height of imageView
imageView.getMeasuredWidth();//width of imageView
```

reference : [Trying to get the display size of an image in an ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855218/trying-to-get-the-display-size-of-an-image-in-an-imageview)

Comment: what will be the result of your solution - px or dp ?

Comment: get the original **dimensions.** of a Image

Comment: didn't get you...can u plz explain ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855218/trying-to-get-the-display-size-of-an-image-in-an-imageview **Follow this link** for batter understanding

Comment: see my Update answer @PragyaMendiratta

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
int w = b.getWidth(); 
int h = b.getHeight(); // height of your image
```

**P.S** :- `h` IS HEIGHT OF IMAGE ( **Original Image Height** )

**Update**

If you want to get the exact height of the image *inside* the imageView try this :-

```
int height = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
int height_in_dp = Math.round(height / (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
```

`height_in_dp` is the **height** of the image in **dp** !!

Comment: getting my app crashed : ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

Comment: @PragyaMendiratta please check updated the answer ..!!

Comment: I have edited my question with image. plz check my comment in @yahya mukhtar answer....... image height is greater than imageview with the code you have mentioned...

Comment: @PragyaMendiratta updated the answer please check !!

Comment: @PragyaMendiratta please feel free to ask , if you didnt understand  !!

Comment: @shantanu , what if image is not fit in imageView, . . for eg there's black space as shown in the pic posted by pragyaMendiratta , will this include that black space in height/width or not??

Comment: @NirmalPrajapat hii, it should not ...if its `fitXy` instead of `center crop` , it should work by taking the whole height and width !!

Comment: I'm not using scalType . .

Comment: @shantanu:
Even I tried your updated solution...its not giving accurate height of image

Comment: which mobile are you using @PragyaMendiratta

Comment: without black spaces @NirmalPrajapat

Comment: @PragyaMendiratta if you are using large device try `displayMetrics.xxhdpi` instead of `displayMetrics.xdpi`

Comment: @shantanu : I have drawn a view of the same height - calculated according to your updated solution. plz check my updated post

Comment: I am using moto g(2 gen)  and I am not getting option of `displayMetrices.xxhdpi` @shantanu

Comment: @SantanuSur:
did u find any solution for this ?

Comment: Nope if i find out..i will update the answer !! @PragyaMendiratta

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap b =  ((BitmapDrawable) imag.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
int w = b.getWidth();
int h = b.getHeight();
```

Comment: getting following error: ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

Comment: @Pragya check it now.

Comment: I am getting h= 882 and imageview (imagHeight) height with  imageView.getHeight() = 672..........

Comment: according to this bitmap height.. image height is greater than imageview.. that's not right