# How to display text detected from ML Kit and display it on the actual location of the word

Tags: android-camera2, firebase-mlkit, text-recognition, android-graphics, camera-api

I am working on an OCR app for android and am using Camera2Api.I am using 
[android-camera2basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) as a boiler plate code and i used ml kit for text recognition.

Am facing a strange problem the GraphicOverlay Is not scaling properly its only covering half screen.The GraphicOverlay is not drawing properly on the detected words.

[image: Click On this To View The Problem]

As you can see that the graphic overlay is not drawing where it should for example "Stack Exchange Network" graphic overaly is not displaying it on the top of Stack Exchange Network.

Here are my Files

- [Camera2BasicFragment.java](https://github.com/Tanveerdhiman/OcrReader/blob/master/Camera2BasicFragment.java)
- [Text Recognizer Class](https://github.com/Tanveerdhiman/OcrReader/blob/master/TextRecognizer.java)
- [Graphic Overlay](https://github.com/Tanveerdhiman/OcrReader/blob/master/GraphicOverlay.java)
- [Text Graphic](https://github.com/Tanveerdhiman/OcrReader/blob/master/TextGraphic.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that the library detect words on the original `bitmap` that you've passed (with its original width and height), and then returns the location of the words according to that image. 
But the image shown on the screen is a SCALED image with a new width and height to fit the screen or the `imageView`.
So what you wanna do is, rescaling the `bitmap` according to your `imageView` and then pass the new `bitmap`

```
//get the scaled bitmap image with the new width and height showed on the screen
    private Bitmap getScaledBitmap (Bitmap bitmapImage){

        //width and height of original image
        final int imageWidth = bitmapImage.getWidth();
        final int imageHeight = bitmapImage.getHeight();

        //width and height of the imageView
        final int imageViewWidth  = mImageView.getMeasuredWidth();
        final int imageViewHeight = mImageView.getMeasuredHeight();

        final int scaledWidth , scaledHeight;


        if (imageWidth*imageViewHeight <= imageHeight*imageViewWidth) {

            //rescaled width and height of image within ImageView
            scaledWidth = (imageWidth*imageViewHeight)/imageHeight;
            scaledHeight = imageViewHeight;
        }
        else {
            //rescaled width and height of image within ImageView
            scaledWidth = imageViewWidth;
            scaledHeight = (imageHeight*imageViewWidth)/imageWidth;
        }


        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapImage, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, true);
    }
```

---

I used this answer for scaling the image: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13318469/9242141

---

**Edit:** Sorry, I noticed that you're not using Bitmaps in your code and things could be a little different in your case but I think you can find a solution based on this idea as I have faced the same problem as you and this worked perfectly for me.

Comment: it was a very easy problem to solve but i was just making it too complex.The thing that was causing the problem was that i was not using the setCameraInfo method in the graphic overlay i sets the resolution of the graphic overlay.I used that method in the TextRecognizer class and passed in the height and width but flipped and that pretty much solved the problem.