# Image bounds inside image view

Tags: android

I have an image view which has an image inside and the image bounds are different that the bounds of the Imageview. How to get the bound of the image inside the Imageview in Android.

Comment: Can you post your code plz ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the displayed size of an image inside an ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463155/get-the-displayed-size-of-an-image-inside-an-imageview)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
     android:scaleType="centerinside"
     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the size of the underlying image like this :

```
ih=imageView.getMeasuredHeight();//height of imageView
iw=imageView.getMeasuredWidth();//width of imageView
iH=imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();//original height of underlying image
iW=imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();//original width of underlying image
```

You can also fit your image to the ImageView size with :

```
    android:scaleType="fitxy"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

For more info on the scaleType look at : https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide

Best