# How to get the position of a picture inside an ImageView?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a gallery of images with different sizes. Each image is displayed inside an `ImageView` sequentially (through `OnTouchListener`). I need to know the position of the frame of the picture I'm showing relatives to the `ImageView` but with the testing I've done I've only gotten the coordinates of `ImageView`. Any idea?

[image]

I need the values of (x1, y1) and (x2, y2).

Thanks in advance.

This is my class:

```
public class PuzzleView extends ImageView {

protected Paint currentPaint;    

protected boolean drawRect = false;    
protected float left;
protected float top;
protected float right;
protected float bottom;

protected float pixelX;
protected float pixelY;

protected int nChunksX = 5;
protected int nChunksY = 5;

protected int currentWidth = 0;
protected int currentHeight = 0;

public PuzzleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    currentPaint = new Paint();
    currentPaint.setDither(true);
    currentPaint.setColor(0xFF00CC00);  
    currentPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    currentPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    currentPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    currentPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);                           
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    float chunkWidth = currentWidth / nChunksX;
    float chunkHeight = currentHeight / nChunksY;

    float posX = ((int)(pixelX / chunkWidth)) * chunkWidth;
    float posY = ((int)(pixelY / chunkHeight)) * chunkHeight;

    canvas.drawRect(posX, posY, posX + chunkWidth, posY + chunkHeight, currentPaint);

    Rect rect = this.getDrawable().getBounds();
    canvas.drawRect(rect, currentPaint);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    // Get image matrix values and place them in an array
    float[] f = new float[9];
    getImageMatrix().getValues(f);

    // Extract the scale values using the constants (if aspect ratio maintained, scaleX == scaleY)
    final float scaleX = f[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
    final float scaleY = f[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];

    // Get the drawable (could also get the bitmap behind the drawable and getWidth/getHeight)
    final Drawable d = getDrawable();
    final int origW = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
    final int origH = d.getIntrinsicHeight();

    // Calculate the actual dimensions
    final int actW = Math.round(origW * scaleX);
    final int actH = Math.round(origH * scaleY);

    currentWidth = actW;
    currentHeight = actH;
}

public boolean isDrawRect() {
    return drawRect;
}

public void setDrawRect(boolean drawRect) {
    this.drawRect = drawRect;
}

public float getLeftRect() {
    return left;
}

public void setLeftRect(float left) {
    this.left = left;
}

public float getTopRect() {
    return top;
}

public void setTopRect(float top) {
    this.top = top;
}

public float getRightRect() {
    return right;
}

public void setRightRect(float right) {
    this.right = right;
}

public float getBottomRect() {
    return bottom;
}

public void setBottomRect(float bottom) {
    this.bottom = bottom;
}

public float getPixelX() {
    return pixelX;
}

public void setPixelX(float pixelX) {
    this.pixelX = pixelX;
}

public float getPixelY() {
    return pixelY;
}

public void setPixelY(float pixelY) {
    this.pixelY = pixelY;
}

public int getChunksX() {
    return nChunksX;
}

public void setChunksX(int nChunksX) {
    this.nChunksX = nChunksX;
}

public int getChunksY() {
    return nChunksY;
}

public void setChunksY(int nChunksY) {         
    this.nChunksY = nChunksY;
}
}
```

For now, the source image is defined in XML file:

```
<com.jocajica.shakepic.PuzzleView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewSelected"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_selected"
    android:src="@android:drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal" />
```

I need to draw a grid over the image.

Comment: What's wrong with getTop/getLeft/getBottom/getRight ?

Comment: @blackbelt I believe these will return the coordinates of the ImageView within its container.  The OP wants to know the offset of the actual image within ImageView

Comment: Exactly. I need to know the offset of the current image and the getTop/getLeft/getBottom/getRight only return the coordinates of the ImageView within its container.

Answer (score 17):

According to Jacob Nordfalk's link, I was able to produce a static method allowing you to get the image position and dimensions from an ImageView.

```
/**
 * Returns the bitmap position inside an imageView.
 * @param imageView source ImageView
 * @return 0: left, 1: top, 2: width, 3: height
 */
public static int[] getBitmapPositionInsideImageView(ImageView imageView) {
    int[] ret = new int[4];

    if (imageView == null || imageView.getDrawable() == null)
        return ret;

    // Get image dimensions
    // Get image matrix values and place them in an array
    float[] f = new float[9];
    imageView.getImageMatrix().getValues(f);

    // Extract the scale values using the constants (if aspect ratio maintained, scaleX == scaleY)
    final float scaleX = f[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
    final float scaleY = f[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];

    // Get the drawable (could also get the bitmap behind the drawable and getWidth/getHeight)
    final Drawable d = imageView.getDrawable();
    final int origW = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
    final int origH = d.getIntrinsicHeight();

    // Calculate the actual dimensions
    final int actW = Math.round(origW * scaleX);
    final int actH = Math.round(origH * scaleY);

    ret[2] = actW;
    ret[3] = actH;

    // Get image position
    // We assume that the image is centered into ImageView
    int imgViewW = imageView.getWidth();
    int imgViewH = imageView.getHeight();

    int top = (int) (imgViewH - actH)/2;
    int left = (int) (imgViewW - actW)/2;

    ret[0] = left;
    ret[1] = top;

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: This will returns offsets in negative value.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `res[2] = left + actW;` and `res[3] = top + actH;`?

Comment: No @Zach. res[2] and res[3], as stated in the comment doc, are the width and height and not the right and bottom

Comment: Thank you Quentis S. and Jacob Nordfalk for the very usefull routine. I took the liberty of changing the return value from an array to a Rect object. See my answer bellow.

Answer (score 3):

You should use getImageMatrix():

```
float[] imageMatrix = new float[9];
getImageMatrix().getValues(imageMatrix);
scale = imageMatrix[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
transX = imageMatrix[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
```

See also
[Trying to get the display size of an image in an ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855218/trying-to-get-the-display-size-of-an-image-in-an-imageview)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Quentis S. and Jacob Nordfalk for the very usefull routine.

I took the liberty of changing the return value from an array to a Rect object.

```
    /**
 * Returns the bitmap position inside an imageView.
 *
 * @param imageView source ImageView
 * @return Rect position of the bitmap in the ImageView
 */
public static final Rect getBitmapPositionInsideImageView(ImageView imageView)
{
    Rect rect = new Rect();

    if (imageView == null || imageView.getDrawable() == null)
    {
        return rect;
    }

    // Get image dimensions
    // Get image matrix values and place them in an array
    float[] f = new float[9];
    imageView.getImageMatrix().getValues(f);

    // Extract the scale values using the constants (if aspect ratio maintained, scaleX == scaleY)
    final float scaleX = f[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
    final float scaleY = f[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];

    // Get the drawable (could also get the bitmap behind the drawable and getWidth/getHeight)
    final Drawable d     = imageView.getDrawable();
    final int      origW = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
    final int      origH = d.getIntrinsicHeight();

    // Calculate the actual dimensions
    final int actW = Math.round(origW * scaleX);
    final int actH = Math.round(origH * scaleY);

    // Get image position
    // We assume that the image is centered into ImageView
    int imgViewW = imageView.getWidth();
    int imgViewH = imageView.getHeight();

    rect.top  = (int) (imgViewH - actH) / 2;
    rect.left = (int) (imgViewW - actW) / 2;

    rect.bottom = rect.top + actH;
    rect.right  = rect.left + actW;

    return rect;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Override the onLayout method

```
    //inside puzzleView
    float[] matrix = new float[9];
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {

        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        matrix = getMatrix();

    }    
    public void getMatrix(){
         return matrix;
    }


    private float[] getMatrix() {

        final float[] matrix = new float[9];
        getImageMatrix().getValues(matrix);

        return matrix;
    }
```

and use this to get values

```
       // Extract the scale and translation values from the matrix.
       float scaleX = matrix[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
       float scaleY = matrix[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];
       float transX = matrix[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
       float transY = matrix[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
```

I hope that this help u