# Logic to find out empty bound between image view and bitmap drawn

Tags: android, bitmap, android-widget

I have a bitmap with resolution of `1024X748` and am applying that to image view of `1280X696`.

Bitmap is drawn into imageview but It did not fill entire view as it maintains aspect ratio . I want to get the space between image view and bitmap drawn into that.

Please help is there any API and logic to get it.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

in your imageview in your xml

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have got it worked through solution in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855218/trying-to-get-the-display-size-of-an-image-in-an-imageview