# how to use custom ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have found the following code on how to get display height and width from ImageView: [Trying to get the display size of an image in an ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855218/trying-to-get-the-display-size-of-an-image-in-an-imageview) . When I try to use it in the layout snippet below, I get following error.

```
 <com.mycompany.widget.SizeAwareImageView
                android:id="@+id/account_profile_img"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/avatar"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="onEditPhotoClicked" />
```

ERROR:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.myapp/com.company.myapp.RegisterActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #218: Error inflating class com.company.myapp.widget.SizeAwareImageView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #218: Error inflating class com.company.myapp.widget.SizeAwareImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:602)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:693)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:327)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
    at com.company.myapp.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:63)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
    ... 11 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:567)
    ... 25 more
```

**UPDATE**

From the graphics Layout I also get the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.company.myapp.widget.SizeAwareImageView.onMeasure(SizeAwareImageView.java:66)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1052)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1217)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:321)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
```

**SECOND UPDATE**

the errored line in question is the second of

```
final Drawable d = getDrawable();
final int origW = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
final int origH = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
```

The complete code is here on stack overflow at [Trying to get the display size of an image in an ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855218/trying-to-get-the-display-size-of-an-image-in-an-imageview) . It's the response with the most votes.

Comment: Looks like there's no SizeAwareImageView(Context context,AttributeSet attr) constructor or your path to the class is wrong

Comment: Thanks. +1. Now I am getting a new error. See my **Update** section

Comment: your trace says SizeAwareImageView.java:66 which means your issue is an NPE on line 66. You'll need to post the relevant method from SizeAwareImageView for anyone to be able to help you

Comment: I already provided the link. It's actually a code snippet here on stack overflow. But I will add the snippet anyway.

Comment: @jqpubliq any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have provided the right constructor for the XML. Your custom Views constructor should have the following method signature:

```
public SizeAwareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
  // todo
}
```

I'm guessing it currently looks like this:

```
public SizeAwareImageView(Context context){
  // todo
}
```

Also I'd double check you meant to set the XML parameter `android:background`, for ImageView you actually set `android:src`.

Comment: Thanks. +1. Now I am getting a new error. See my Update section

Comment: ah. I forgot the `src`. Now it's working. Except when I try to get width and height, I can values less than zero.