# Get image dimensions after it draws in screen

Tags: android, imageview, scale

I have an `ImageView` with `MathParent` height and width
In my activity it loads a pic from resource to `ImageView`. How can i get width and height of the picture inside the `ImageView` AFTER it has been scaled.
I have not set the `android:scaleType` in XML
these dimensions i mean!
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why do you want this? As there might be easier solutions than knowing the size of the image.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855218/trying-to-get-the-display-size-of-an-image-in-an-imageview

Comment: @weston I need this cause i want to show user some specific points at fixed dimensions of this pic. as my app is going to run on different screen sizes, i can't use `dp` or `px` in my code.

Comment: Yeah, so you don't need the size, map the points with the matrix as seen in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a lot with the [matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#getImageMatrix()) the view uses to display the image.

Here I calculate the scale the image is drawn at:

```
private float scaleOfImageView(ImageView image) {
    float[] coords = new float[]{0, 0, 1, 1};
    Matrix matrix = image.getImageMatrix();
    matrix.mapPoints(coords);
    return coords[2] - coords[0]; //xscale, method assumes maintaining aspect ratio
}
```

Applying the scale to the image dimensions gives the displayed image size:

```
private void logImageDisplaySize(ImageView image) {
    Drawable drawable = image.getDrawable();
    int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    float scale = scaleOfImageView(image);
    float displayedWidth = scale * width;
    float displayedHeight = scale * height;
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("Image drawn at scale: %.2f => %.2f x %.2f",
            scale, displayedWidth, displayedHeight));
}
```

I suspect you don't really care about the image size, I suspect you want to map touch points back to a coordinate on the image, this answer shows how to do this (also using the image matrix): https://stackoverflow.com/a/9945896/360211